NSScrollView doesn't show scrollbars in macOS Sonoma
I have a Swift 4 app with an NSView showing data diagrams in an NSScrollView.
That worked well until macOS 12. I didn't use any constraints.
Diagram in the app:

Now in macOS 14 and Swift 5, the scrollbars are not shown any more in the storyboard. Seems they are hidden by the contentView.
I am not able to set any constraints to move the contentView from the bottom of the scrollView.
Diagram without Srollers in the app:

Storyboard settings:

Any ideas or links to fix this?

Which view is selected in the bottom image? What are the scroll bar visibility settings of the NSScrollView and system prefs?

visibility settings in system settings to show always did it. Thank you.
